# CSS selector not working in {N}

Tags: nativescript

I've got the following in the XML file

`<Button id="note" text="" tap="onNote" class="my-note" />`

In the css file, I have:

Button[class='my-note'] {font-family: 'FontAwesome'; }

This doesn't seem to work - but id selector does work.

Button[id='note'] {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
button.my-note {font-family: 'FontAwesome'; }
```

This works for me.